# Is it allowed to say thanks and sorry to a person for his favour or your mistakes?

Tags: practical-islam, islamic-basis

I want to know like some person give me water when I was thirsty , so I thanked Allah for water and thanked the person too , I realised I should not say thanks to a non muslim or muslim I have to say may Allah bless you , is that right (similar case for sorry ) or I am allowed to say thanks and sorry ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a hadith which strongly encourages being grateful to people:

> Whoever is not grateful to the people, he is not grateful to Allah.
> <sub>[Jami` at-Tirmidhi 1955](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/27/61) [grade: sahih]</sub>
>
> He who does not thank the people is not thankful to Allah.
> <sub>[Sunan Abi Dawud 4811](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/43/39) [grade: sahih]</sub>

And a hadith which strongly encourages seeking forgiveness from people:

> Whoever has wronged his brother, should ask for his pardon ...
> <sub>[Sahih al-Bukhari 6534](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/81/123)</sub>

These ahadith are among many others which implore good manners in general:

> The most beloved to me amongst you is the one who has the best character and manners.
> <sub>[Sahih al-Bukhari 3759, 3760](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3759)</sub>

And there doesn't seem to be a major distinction between Muslims and non-Muslims (*It is incumbent on the Muslim to seek forgiveness from the non-Muslim* [IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&lang=E&Id=281386); see also [IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&lang=E&Id=284845)).